How to implement a multi-level drilldown?
!! Updating with info from Jan in answer. He has clearly showed how to do this using my first dataset below, df3.  Working backwards I tried to apply his method to the three separate datasets in my final example, and the drilldowns cannot reference higher levels unless all the data is in one dataframe. This is paramount as the key aspect approach in some of the links shows dataframes of only 2 columns for each drilldown, BUT they must be coming from an overall larger one where all the links are implicit.
Joining the dataframes in my final example and approaching using Jan's method I've included a working example to see how the data needs to be arranged and how it is working.
I'm trying to do a multiple level drilldown and not sure which approach to take or what way the data should be to start with. Following a number of paths jkunst stackoverflow infoworld I've tried two methods, the first kind of works, but is doubling everything in the stacking: should have 2 in the stacked bar chart: Type; Stationary, Household. The first level is messed up.
 df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,  ~Full_Total,   ~Total,      ~Type,      ~Sub_Type,           ~Count,     
  1990,       40,         35,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             20,
  1990,       40,         35,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              15,             
  1990,       40,          5,      "Household",   "Dishes",               5,
  1990,       40,          5,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",    0,
  1991,       60,         30,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             30,
  1991,       60,         25,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              25,             
  1991,       60,          0,      "Household",   "Dishes",               0,
  1991,       60,          5,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",    5,
  1992,       90,         40,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             30,
  1992,       90,         40,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              10,             
  1992,       90,         50,      "Household",   "Dishes",              40,
  1992,       90,         50,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",   10,
  )

df3 <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(Year = fct_inorder(as.character(Year)))
# ---- drilldown using df3

drilldown <- df3 %>% 
  group_nest(Year) %>% 
  mutate(id = Year,
         type = "column",
         data = map(data, mutate, name = `Type`, y = `Count`),
         data = map(data, list_parse)
  )



 drilldown2 <- df3 %>% 
  group_nest(Year) %>% 
  mutate(id = Year,
         type = "column",
         data = map(data, mutate, name = "Sub_Type", y = "Count"),
         data = map(data, list_parse)
         )
    
    # ---- data is ready for drilldown charting ----
    
    # ---- chart ----
    
    hchart(
      df3,
      "column",
      hcaes(x = Year, y = `Total`, name = Type, drilldown = Year),
      name = "Full Total",
      colorByPoint = TRUE
    ) |>
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")
      )|>
  hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = list_parse(drilldown)
      )|>
  hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = list_parse(drilldown2)
  )

So the code above kind of works/ works incorrectly to first level but adding a list of lists to hc_drilldown e.g. to make more drilldowns doesn't work
hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list_parse(drilldown),
      list_parse(drilldown2)
    )

Yet another way as follows, should work and would facilitate further drilldowns but I can't get it to work.
    df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Total,~Type,
  1990,    450,  "Stationary",
  1990,    450,  "Food",
  1990,    450,  "Household", 
  1991,    600,  "Stationary",
  1991,    600,  "Food", 
  1991,    600,  "Household",
  1992,    170,  "Stationary", 
  1992,    170,  "Food", 
  1992,    170,  "Household", 
  1993,    253,  "Stationary", 
  1993,    253,  "Food", 
  1993,    253,  "Household")

df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(Year = as.character(Year)) %>% mutate(Year = fct(Year))

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Sub_Total,~Sub_Type,
  1990,     100,  "pencils",
  1990,     200,  "bread",
  1990,     150,  "bulbs", 
  1991,     200,  "pens",
  1991,     200,  "milk", 
  1991,     200,  "dishes",
  1992,      50,  "ruler", 
  1992,     100,  "meat", 
  1992,      20,  "cleaning", 
  1993,     150,  "rubber", 
  1993,     100,  "fruit", 
  1993,       3,  "containers")

df2 <- df2 %>% select(!Year)

# ---- drilldown using df1 and df2

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Basic Drilldown") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      borderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE)
    ),
    column = list(stacking = "normal")
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    data = df1, 
    type = "column",
    hcaes(name = "Year", y = Total/3),
    name = "Type", 
    colorByPoint=TRUE
  )

drilldown1 <- df2[c(1,4,7,10),]


drilldown2 <- df2[c(2,5,8,11),]
  
drilldown3 <- df2[c(3,6,9,12),]
  

drilldown1 <- list_parse2(drilldown1)
drilldown2 <- list_parse2(drilldown2)
drilldown3 <- list_parse2(drilldown3)

hc <- hc %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "Stationary",
        data = drilldown1),
      list(
        id = "Food",
        data = drilldown2
      ),
      list(
        id = "Household",
        data = drilldown3
      )
  )
)

Lastly, trying to ensure key aspect is correct and following this example make_3_level_drilldown_highcharter, but not getting the drilldown working.
  main_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,   ~Type,    ~Total,
  1990,  "Primary",    100,
  1991,  "Primary",    200,
  1992,  "Primary",    300,
  1993,  "Primary",    400
)

sub_type_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,  ~Sub_Type,   ~Sub_Count,
  1990,      "A",            25,
  1990,      "B",            15,
  1990,      "C",            15,
  1990,      "D",            20,
  1990,      "E",            30,
  1991,      "A",            50,
  1991,      "B",            50,
  1991,      "C",            25,
  1991,      "D",            25,
  1991,      "E",            50,
  1992,      "A",            20,
  1992,      "B",            70,
  1992,      "C",            60,
  1992,      "D",           100,
  1992,      "E",            50,
  1993,      "A",            75,
  1993,      "B",            25,
  1993,      "C",           150,
  1993,      "D",           100,
  1993,      "E",            50,
)

parts_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,   ~Sub_Type,  ~Part,  ~Part_Count,
  1990,       "A",     "part-a",     5,
  1990,       "A",     "part-b",     5,
  1990,       "A",     "part-c",    10,
  1990,       "A",     "part-d",     5,
  1990,       "B",     "part-a",     0, 
  1990,       "B",     "part-b",     5,
  1990,       "B",     "part-c",     5,
  1990,       "B",     "part-d",     5,
  1990,       "C",     "part-a",     5,
  1990,       "C",     "part-b",     0,
  1990,       "C",     "part-c",     5,
  1990,       "C",     "part-d",     5,
  1990,       "D",     "part-a",    10,
  1990,       "D",     "part-b",     0,
  1990,       "D",     "part-c",     5,
  1990,       "D",     "part-d",     5,
  1990,       "E",     "part-a",    15,
  1990,       "E",     "part-b",     0, 
  1990,       "E",     "part-c",    10,
  1990,       "E",     "part-d",     5,
  1991,       "A",     "part-a",    20,
  1991,       "A",     "part-b",    15,
  1991,       "A",     "part-c",    10,
  1991,       "A",     "part-d",     5,
  1991,       "B",     "part-a",    15, 
  1991,       "B",     "part-b",    20,
  1991,       "B",     "part-c",     5,
  1991,       "B",     "part-d",    10,
  1991,       "C",     "part-a",     5,
  1991,       "C",     "part-b",     0,
  1991,       "C",     "part-c",    15,
  1991,       "C",     "part-d",     5,
  1991,       "D",     "part-a",    10,
  1991,       "D",     "part-b",     0,
  1991,       "D",     "part-c",    10,
  1991,       "D",     "part-d",     5,
  1991,       "E",     "part-a",    15,
  1991,       "E",     "part-b",    10, 
  1991,       "E",     "part-c",    10,
  1991,       "E",     "part-d",    15,
  1992,       "A",     "part-a",     5,
  1992,       "A",     "part-b",     5,
  1992,       "A",     "part-c",    10,
  1992,       "A",     "part-d",     0,
  1992,       "B",     "part-a",    20, 
  1992,       "B",     "part-b",    15,
  1992,       "B",     "part-c",     5,
  1992,       "B",     "part-d",    30,
  1992,       "C",     "part-a",    20,
  1992,       "C",     "part-b",    20,
  1992,       "C",     "part-c",    15,
  1992,       "C",     "part-d",     5,
  1992,       "D",     "part-a",    10,
  1992,       "D",     "part-b",    60,
  1992,       "D",     "part-c",    15,
  1992,       "D",     "part-d",    15,
  1992,       "E",     "part-a",    15,
  1992,       "E",     "part-b",    20, 
  1992,       "E",     "part-c",    10,
  1992,       "E",     "part-d",     5,
  1993,       "A",     "part-a",    25,
  1993,       "A",     "part-b",    25,
  1993,       "A",     "part-c",    10,
  1993,       "A",     "part-d",    15,
  1993,       "B",     "part-a",    10, 
  1993,       "B",     "part-b",     5,
  1993,       "B",     "part-c",     5,
  1993,       "B",     "part-d",     5,
  1993,       "C",     "part-a",    80,
  1993,       "C",     "part-b",    20,
  1993,       "C",     "part-c",    15,
  1993,       "C",     "part-d",    35,
  1993,       "D",     "part-a",    10,
  1993,       "D",     "part-b",    40,
  1993,       "D",     "part-c",    25,
  1993,       "D",     "part-d",    25,
  1993,       "E",     "part-a",    15,
  1993,       "E",     "part-b",    20, 
  1993,       "E",     "part-c",    10,
  1993,       "E",     "part-d",     5,
  
)

full_df <- left_join(main_df, parts_df)

datSum <- full_df |>
  summarize(Quantity = sum(Total), .by = Year)
Lvl1dfStatus <-
  tibble(
    name = datSum$Year,
    y = datSum$Quantity,
    drilldown = tolower(name)
  )


drilldownLvl2 <- lapply(unique(full_df$Year), function(year_level) {
  datSum2 <- full_df |> 
    filter(Year == year_level) |> 
    summarise(Quantity = sum(Part_Count), .by = Sub_Type) 
  Lvl2dfStatus <-
    tibble(
      name = datSum2$Sub_Type,
      y = datSum2$Quantity,
      drilldown = tolower(paste(year_level, name, sep = "_"))
    )
  list(
    id = tolower(year_level),
    name = "Type",
    type = "column",
    data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus)
  )
})

drilldownLvl3 <- lapply(unique(full_df$Year), function(year_level) {
  datSum2 <- full_df |> 
    filter(Year == year_level)
  lapply(unique(datSum2$Sub_Type), function(type_level) {
    datSum3 <- datSum2 %>% 
      filter(Sub_Type == type_level) %>% 
      summarise(Quantity = sum(Part_Count), .by = Part)
    Lvl3dfStatus <-
      tibble(name = datSum3$Part, y = datSum3$Quantity)
    list(
      id = tolower(paste(year_level, type_level, sep = "_")),
      name = "Part",
      type = "column",
      data = list_parse2(Lvl3dfStatus)
    )
  })
}) |> unlist(recursive = FALSE)

highchart() |>
  hc_title(text = "Basic multi-level drilldown") |> 
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") |>
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Count")) |> 
  hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus,
                "column",
                hcaes(
                  x = name,
                  y = y,
                  name = name,
                  drilldown = drilldown
                ),
                name = "Year") |>
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) |> 
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = c(drilldownLvl2, drilldownLvl3))


It's not really clear for me what you problem is. That everything is doubling inside the stacking is clear since you are relying on the Total column of your data and this column looks like what you see in the diagram. Why don't you use e.g. data = map(data, mutate, name = Type, y = Total)?

That's great Jan, I missed that: changed Total to Count so now not doubling. So I'm using data = map(data, mutate etc... in the example with df3. It's how to add a second drilldown using this method that's flumoxing me. Have tried  hc_drilldown(
allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
series =
list_parse(drilldown)
)|>
hc_drilldown(
allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
series =
list_parse(drilldown2)
)

It's a little bit more complex with multi-level drilldowns. Below is an example based on your first code how you could wrangle your data in order to obtain suitable lists.
However, notice that a three-level-drilldown is not really needed here since your data only has two kind of types. I included it since the code in your question tries to use multiple drilldown levels.

library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,  ~Full_Total,   ~Total,      ~Type,      ~Sub_Type,           ~Count,     
  1990,       40,         35,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             20,
  1990,       40,         35,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              15,             
  1990,       40,          5,      "Household",   "Dishes",               5,
  1990,       40,          5,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",    0,
  1991,       60,         30,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             30,
  1991,       60,         25,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              25,             
  1991,       60,          0,      "Household",   "Dishes",               0,
  1991,       60,          5,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",    5,
  1992,       90,         40,     "Stationary",   "Pencils",             30,
  1992,       90,         40,     "Stationary",   "Rulers",              10,             
  1992,       90,         50,      "Household",   "Dishes",              40,
  1992,       90,         50,      "Household",   "Cleaning_products",   10,
)


datSum <- df3 |>
  summarize(Quantity = sum(Count), .by = Year)
Lvl1dfStatus <-
  tibble(
    name = datSum$Year,
    y = datSum$Quantity,
    drilldown = tolower(name)
  )


drilldownLvl2 <- lapply(unique(df3$Year), function(year_level) {
  datSum2 <- df3 |> 
    filter(Year == year_level) |> 
    summarise(Quantity = sum(Count), .by = Type) |> 
    arrange(desc(Quantity))
  Lvl2dfStatus <-
    tibble(
      name = datSum2$Type,
      y = datSum2$Quantity,
      drilldown = tolower(paste(year_level, name, sep = "_"))
    )
  list(
    id = tolower(year_level),
    name = "Type",
    type = "column",
    data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus)
  )
})


drilldownLvl3 <- lapply(unique(df3$Year), function(year_level) {
  datSum2 <- df3 |> filter(Year == year_level)
  lapply(unique(datSum2$Type), function(type_level) {
    datSum3 <- datSum2 |> 
      filter(Type == type_level) |> 
      summarise(Quantity = sum(Count), .by = Sub_Type) |> 
      arrange(desc(Quantity))
    Lvl3dfStatus <-
      tibble(name = datSum3$Sub_Type, y = datSum3$Quantity)
    list(
      id = tolower(paste(year_level, type_level, sep = "_")),
      name = "Sub_Type",
      type = "column",
      data = list_parse2(Lvl3dfStatus)
    )
  })
}) |> unlist(recursive = FALSE)

highchart() |>
  hc_title(text = "Basic multi-level drilldown") |> 
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") |>
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Count")) |> 
  hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus,
                "column",
                hcaes(
                  x = name,
                  y = y,
                  name = name,
                  drilldown = drilldown
                ),
                name = "Year") |>
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) |>
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = c(drilldownLvl2, drilldownLvl3))


Jan thank you so much, you've made it clear to me how the connections are operating. Have updated above to apply your method to the third example of separate datasets. There needs to be one unified master dataset for the drilldowns to reference back to inexplicitly. Trialed with the three datasets separately then joined to work back in your code and see how it all works together. That is fantastic, it was hard to bring all the disparate approaches together until you worked through in your example
